# Continuity of minimizer of a function with respect to another variable

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

Suppose the real function $f(w,X)=wg(X)+h(X)$ ($g$ and $h$ are other functions) is differentiable with respect to scalar $w$ and vector $X \in \mathbf{R}^m$ everywhere and $f$ is bounded below.  What conditions are sufficient to show that $\arg\min_{X}{f(X)}$ is continuous with respect to $w$?

Comment: This is not easy in general. Convexity of $g$ and $h$ is helpful (while differentiability is not that important).

Comment: would it help if it was locally convex around any local minimum?